# Add content to a tfoot in a table with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have this example table

```
<table border="1" id="tabla">
 <tr>
  <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
  <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
  <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I try to add content dynamically with Jquery with this

```
$("#tabla").find('tfoot').append($('<td><b>Total</b></td><td>a</td><td>b</td>'));
```

But, don't works

If a use firebug to inspect table, this have a tfoot but empty. ¿How to add dynamically content to a tfoot without added content previously?

Comment: U got two viable answers u might wanna pick one ? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a solution without changing your html would be to add the tfoot first:

```
$(function($){
    var foot = $("#tabla").find('tfoot');
    if (!foot.length) foot = $('<tfoot>').appendTo("#tabla"); 
    foot.append($('<td><b>Total</b></td><td>a</td><td>b</td>'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an explicit `tfoot` tag on your HTML

```
<table border="1" id="tabla">
 <tr>
  <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
  <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
  <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```